# C# Sorting words from xml file to text file in alphabetical order

Tags: c#, xml

I’m working on a C# program that converts the contents of an xml document to a txt file and I’m struggling on adding conditions like inputting the words in ascending order of size. I have entered a condition to prevents lowercase words from being entered and I would like to know if either a similar method can be used to return the words in alphabetical order or if that isn't possible, what would be a good alternative. My condition for no lowercase letters is as followed:

```
 internal static bool NoLowerCase(String WORDS)          
 {
    return WORDS.All(c => c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z');
 }
```

Comment: So all your words are inside a single string?

Comment: Well, for your example, you'd be better off using the [`IsUpper`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isupper%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.  `c => c.IsUpper())`  As for your alphabetical order, you should just put the words in a list and sort them.

Comment: yes they are all inside a single string

Comment: You can use a list to hold all the words and then apply any filter you want on it, and also sort the list by alphabetical order...

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you have a given XML file, it already has a fixed order. Do you mean you want to *output* the words in sorted order?

Comment: Yes, I want the output words in sorted order. Sorry for not making that clear

Comment: You have tagged your question `[xml]`. Is it correct that your question actually is *not* about XML, but about strings (and testing whether a `string` meets a specific condition)?

Comment: yeah, that is correct

Answer (score 1):

You're title threw me off the first time, I thought you wanted it in alphabetic order. This should sort the list by length.

```
var sorted = from s in e
             orderby s.Length ascending
             select s;
return sorted;
```

http://www.dotnetperls.com/sort-strings-length

Answer (score 0):

if you add all the WORDS you have into a list, you can simply call list.Sort().

That should sort the words for you.

Comment: I tried this but it gave the output in alphabetical order, not by length size

Answer (score 0):

I assume that all your `Words` are separete by a space.
Here is my solution:

```
string x = "aaa bbbb ddd ccc";

var words = x.Split(' ').ToList();
var orderedList = words.OrderBy(value => value.Lenght);

Console.WriteLine (orderedList);
```

the output:

[image]